# Divide by zero generates an error on mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6"),
    "activity" : {
        "a1": 10,
        "a2": 11,
        "a3": 12,
        "a4": 13,
        "a5": 14,
        "b1": 5,
        "b2": 6
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This is a dummy entries, actual Entries will be around 50 or 60 out of that 30 are from simple addition (like from a1 to a5) and 20 entries are for ratio (like b1 and b2).
For asking the concept I minimize the dataset

Now from a1 to a5 I have to do addition with some weightage value of multiplication like this:
lets say multiplication value is 0.5

```
so it will be like this:
(a1*0.5 + a2*0.5 + a3*0.5 + a4*0.5 + a5*0.5)
```

and then I have to take the ratio of b1 and b2 and then multiply be some weightage  like this

```
((b1:b2)*0.5)
```

So final calculation will be like this:

```
(a1*0.5 + a2*0.5 + a3*0.5 + a4*0.5 + a5*0.5 + (b1:b2)*0.5)
```

For that I used mongodb aggregation. My code is this:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6") } },
  { $unwind: "$_id" },
  {
    $project: {
      "activity.score": {
        $add: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a1",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a2",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a3",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a4",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$activity.a5",
              0.5
            ]
          },
          {
            $multiply: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  "$activity.b1",
                  "$activity.b2"
                ]
              },
              0.5
            ]
          }

        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

By this I got the answer, but in case my b2 will be 0 like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6"),
    "activity" : {
        "a1": 10,
        "a2": 11,
        "a3": 12,
        "a4": 13,
        "a5": 14,
        "b1": 5,
        "b2": 0
    }
}
```

MongoDB generates an error i.e **MongoError: can't $divide by zero**.
Is there anyone who can suggest me How to achieve this. Any help or suggestion is really appreciable for that. Thanks in advance for the effort and interaction.

Comment: So you're asking how to solve the `divide by zero error` if your `b2` is actually 0?

Comment: @molamk exactly like this

Comment: You can't do that with that formula though

Comment: It generates an error which I mentioned

Comment: I mean you can't fix that because your `b2` may be equal to `0`. You need to change the formula or restrict values of `b2` to never be equal to `0`

Comment: You have to put `$cond` if `b2 === 0` then do something and if not then do multiplication.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet can you elaborate where i have to use the condition

Comment: could you explain if `b2` is not equal to `0` then this `(b1:b2)*0.5` and if it is equal to `0` then ?? what you want here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I need the concept by which if b2 is zero then that calculation will be by passed. Like this:(10*0.5 + 11*0.5+ 12*0.5+ 13*0.5 + 14*0.5) + ((5:0)*0.5) == in that case take 0 value for second part that is ratio part

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet so that case answer will be : 30 + ((5:0)*0.5). so treat this case as 30 + 0 i.e 30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this it works!

```
{
  "activity.score": {
    $add: [
      {
        $multiply: [
          "$activity.a1",
          0.5
        ]
      },
      {
        $multiply: [
          "$activity.a2",
          0.5
        ]
      },
      {
        $multiply: [
          "$activity.a3",
          0.5
        ]
      },
      {
        $multiply: [
          "$activity.a4",
          0.5
        ]
      },
      {
        $multiply: [
          "$activity.a5",
          0.5
        ]
      },
      {
        $multiply: [
         { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$activity.b2", 0 ] }, 0,  {
            $divide: [
              "$activity.b1",
              "$activity.b2"
            ]
          }
       ] }
         ,
          0.5
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```